# Why Showing empty windows form not showing any controls in c# project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I designed some Windows form a few days back. After a few days, all controls have disappeared from  the form. It seems just like a new blank form. This form is the startup form and it is there in the Program.cs file. Also, I've not edited the designer.cs file manually.

**here is my FrmMain.cs code**

```
public partial class FrmMain : Form
    {
        private bool isCollapsed=true;

        public FrmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            GetDateAndTime();
            sidePanel.Top = btnHome.Top;
        }

        private void GetDateAndTime()
        {
            try {
                timer1.Start();
                lblTme.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
                lblDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();

            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Clipboard.SetText(e.Message);
            }

        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblTme.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
            timer1.Start();
        }



        private void btnSettings_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            sidePanel.Top = panelCollap.Top;
            timer2.Start();
        }

        private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (isCollapsed)
            {
                panelCollap.Height += 10;
                if (panelCollap.Size == panelCollap.MaximumSize) {

                    timer2.Stop();
                    isCollapsed = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                panelCollap.Height -= 10;
                if (panelCollap.Size == panelCollap.MinimumSize)
                {

                    timer2.Stop();
                    isCollapsed = true;
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

**Here is the Designer.cs**

```
 partial class FrmMain
    {

        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(FrmMain));
            this.flowLayoutPanel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel();
            this.pictureBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
            this.btnHome = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.btnMasterFiles = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.btnEmplyeeCenter = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.btnPayroll = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.btnAttendence = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.btnLeave = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.btnPerformance = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.btnNoticeBoard = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.panelCollap = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
            this.btnUserSetup = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.btnComanySetup = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.btnSettings = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.panel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
            this.panel3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
            this.lblDate = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.lblTme = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.pictureBox3 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
            this.pictureBox2 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
            this.pictureBox4 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
            this.menuStrip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.MenuStrip();
            this.fileToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.hmeToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.masterToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.employeeToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.payrllToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.attendenceToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.leaveToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.performanceToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.noticeToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.settingToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.sidePanel = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
            this.timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(this.components);
            this.timer2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(this.components);
            this.flowLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).BeginInit();
            this.panelCollap.SuspendLayout();
            this.panel1.SuspendLayout();
            this.panel3.SuspendLayout();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox3)).BeginInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox2)).BeginInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox4)).BeginInit();
            this.menuStrip1.SuspendLayout();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // flowLayoutPanel1
            // 
            this.flowLayoutPanel1.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
            this.flowLayoutPanel1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))));
            this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox1);
            this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.btnHome);
            this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.btnMasterFiles);
            this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.btnEmplyeeCenter);
            this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.btnPayroll);
            this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.btnAttendence);
            this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.btnLeave);
            this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.btnPerformance);
            this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.btnNoticeBoard);
            this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.panelCollap);
            this.flowLayoutPanel1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Left;
            this.flowLayoutPanel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.flowLayoutPanel1.Name = "flowLayoutPanel1";
            this.flowLayoutPanel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(234, 902);
            this.flowLayoutPanel1.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // pictureBox1
            // 
            this.pictureBox1.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("pictureBox1.Image")));
            this.pictureBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(28, 3);
            this.pictureBox1.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(28, 3, 3, 3);
            this.pictureBox1.Name = "pictureBox1";
            this.pictureBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(174, 134);
            this.pictureBox1.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
            this.pictureBox1.TabIndex = 3;
            this.pictureBox1.TabStop = false;
            this.pictureBox1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.pictureBox1_Click);
            // 
            // btnHome
            // 
            this.btnHome.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.btnHome.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
            this.btnHome.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.btnHome.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Century Gothic", 7.8F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.btnHome.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.btnHome.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("btnHome.Image")));
            this.btnHome.ImageAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
            this.btnHome.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 155);
            this.btnHome.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3, 15, 3, 3);
            this.btnHome.Name = "btnHome";
            this.btnHome.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(10, 0, 0, 0);
            this.btnHome.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(228, 69);
            this.btnHome.TabIndex = 0;
            this.btnHome.Text = "Home";
            this.btnHome.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.btnHome.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnHome_Click);
            // 
            // btnMasterFiles
            // 
            this.btnMasterFiles.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.btnMasterFiles.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
            this.btnMasterFiles.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.btnMasterFiles.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Century Gothic", 7.8F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.btnMasterFiles.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.btnMasterFiles.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("btnMasterFiles.Image")));
            this.btnMasterFiles.ImageAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
            this.btnMasterFiles.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 230);
            this.btnMasterFiles.Name = "btnMasterFiles";
            this.btnMasterFiles.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(10, 0, 0, 0);
            this.btnMasterFiles.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(228, 69);
            this.btnMasterFiles.TabIndex = 1;
            this.btnMasterFiles.Text = "Master Files";
            this.btnMasterFiles.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.btnMasterFiles.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnMasterFiles_Click);
            // 
            // btnEmplyeeCenter
            // 
            this.btnEmplyeeCenter.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.btnEmplyeeCenter.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
            this.btnEmplyeeCenter.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.btnEmplyeeCenter.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Century Gothic", 7.8F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.btnEmplyeeCenter.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.btnEmplyeeCenter.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("btnEmplyeeCenter.Image")));
            this.btnEmplyeeCenter.ImageAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
            this.btnEmplyeeCenter.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 305);
            this.btnEmplyeeCenter.Name = "btnEmplyeeCenter";
            this.btnEmplyeeCenter.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(10, 0, 0, 0);
            this.btnEmplyeeCenter.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(228, 69);
            this.btnEmplyeeCenter.TabIndex = 2;
            this.btnEmplyeeCenter.Text = "   Emplyee Center";
            this.btnEmplyeeCenter.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.btnEmplyeeCenter.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnEmplyeeCenter_Click);
            // 
            // btnPayroll
            // 
            this.btnPayroll.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.btnPayroll.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
            this.btnPayroll.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.btnPayroll.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Century Gothic", 7.8F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.btnPayroll.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.btnPayroll.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("btnPayroll.Image")));
            this.btnPayroll.ImageAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
            this.btnPayroll.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 380);
            this.btnPayroll.Name = "btnPayroll";
            this.btnPayroll.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(10, 0, 0, 0);
            this.btnPayroll.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(228, 69);
            this.btnPayroll.TabIndex = 3;
            this.btnPayroll.Text = "Payroll";
            this.btnPayroll.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.btnPayroll.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnPayroll_Click);
// 
            // panelCollap
            // 
            this.panelCollap.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))));
            this.panelCollap.Controls.Add(this.btnUserSetup);
            this.panelCollap.Controls.Add(this.btnComanySetup);
            this.panelCollap.Controls.Add(this.btnSettings);
            this.panelCollap.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 755);
            this.panelCollap.MaximumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(228, 207);
            this.panelCollap.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(228, 69);
            this.panelCollap.Name = "panelCollap";
            this.panelCollap.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(228, 69);
            this.panelCollap.TabIndex = 3;
            // 
            // btnUserSetup
            // 
            this.btnUserSetup.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DimGray;
            this.btnUserSetup.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.btnUserSetup.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
            this.btnUserSetup.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.btnUserSetup.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Century Gothic", 7.8F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.btnUserSetup.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.btnUserSetup.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("btnUserSetup.Image")));
            this.btnUserSetup.ImageAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
            this.btnUserSetup.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 138);
            this.btnUserSetup.Name = "btnUserSetup";
            this.btnUserSetup.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(10, 0, 0, 0);
            this.btnUserSetup.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(228, 69);
            this.btnUserSetup.TabIndex = 10;
            this.btnUserSetup.Text = "User Setup";
            this.btnUserSetup.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            //this.btnUserSetup.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button2_Click);
            ////// 
            // btnComanySetup
            // 
            this.btnComanySetup.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DimGray;
            this.btnComanySetup.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.btnComanySetup.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
            this.btnComanySetup.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.btnComanySetup.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Century Gothic", 7.8F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.btnComanySetup.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.btnComanySetup.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("btnComanySetup.Image")));
            this.btnComanySetup.ImageAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
            this.btnComanySetup.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 69);
            this.btnComanySetup.Name = "btnComanySetup";
            this.btnComanySetup.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(10, 0, 0, 0);
            this.btnComanySetup.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(228, 69);
            this.btnComanySetup.TabIndex = 9;
            this.btnComanySetup.Text = "ComanySetup";
            this.btnComanySetup.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;

            // 
            // panel1
            // 
            this.panel1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))));
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.panel3);
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.menuStrip1);
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.label1);
            this.panel1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Top;
            this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(234, 0);
            this.panel1.Name = "panel1";
            this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1281, 82);
            this.panel1.TabIndex = 1;
            // 
            // panel3
            // 
            this.panel3.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))));
            this.panel3.Controls.Add(this.lblDate);
            this.panel3.Controls.Add(this.lblTme);
            this.panel3.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox3);
            this.panel3.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox2);
            this.panel3.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox4);
            this.panel3.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Right;
            this.panel3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(720, 0); 
            this.panel3.Name = "panel3";
            this.panel3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(561, 82);
            this.panel3.TabIndex = 3;
            // 
            // lblDate
            // 
            this.lblDate.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.lblDate.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(118, 7);
            this.lblDate.Name = "lblDate";
            this.lblDate.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(187, 23);
            this.lblDate.TabIndex = 7;
            this.lblDate.Text = "Date";
            // 
            // lblTme
            // 
            this.lblTme.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.lblTme.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(311, 7);
            this.lblTme.Name = "lblTme";
            this.lblTme.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 29);
            this.lblTme.TabIndex = 6;
            this.lblTme.Text = "Time";
            // 
            // pictureBox3
            // 
            this.pictureBox3.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(128)))), ((int)(((byte)(0)))));
            this.pictureBox3.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("pictureBox3.Image")));
            this.pictureBox3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(484, 5);
            this.pictureBox3.Name = "pictureBox3";
            this.pictureBox3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(27, 26);
            this.pictureBox3.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
            this.pictureBox3.TabIndex = 4;
            this.pictureBox3.TabStop = false;
            // 
            // pictureBox2
            // 
            this.pictureBox2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(128)))), ((int)(((byte)(0)))));
            this.pictureBox2.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("pictureBox2.Image")));
            this.pictureBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(437, 5);
            this.pictureBox2.Name = "pictureBox2";
            this.pictureBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(26, 26);
            this.pictureBox2.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
            this.pictureBox2.TabIndex = 3;
            this.pictureBox2.TabStop = false;
            // 
            // pictureBox4
            // 
            this.pictureBox4.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(128)))), ((int)(((byte)(0)))));
            this.pictureBox4.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("pictureBox4.Image")));
            this.pictureBox4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(527, 5);
            this.pictureBox4.Name = "pictureBox4";
            this.pictureBox4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(32, 26);
            this.pictureBox4.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
            this.pictureBox4.TabIndex = 5;
            this.pictureBox4.TabStop = false;
            this.pictureBox4.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.pictureBox4_Click);
            // 
            // menuStrip1
            // 
            this.menuStrip1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))));
            this.menuStrip1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.None;
            this.menuStrip1.GripMargin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(10);
            this.menuStrip1.ImageScalingSize = new System.Drawing.Size(20, 20);
            this.menuStrip1.Items.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
            this.fileToolStripMenuItem,
            this.hmeToolStripMenuItem,
            this.masterToolStripMenuItem,
            this.employeeToolStripMenuItem,
            this.payrllToolStripMenuItem,
            this.attendenceToolStripMenuItem,
            this.leaveToolStripMenuItem,
            this.performanceToolStripMenuItem,
            this.noticeToolStripMenuItem,
            this.settingToolStripMenuItem});
            this.menuStrip1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 54);
            this.menuStrip1.Name = "menuStrip1";
            this.menuStrip1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(916, 28);
            this.menuStrip1.TabIndex = 3;
            this.menuStrip1.Text = "menuStrip1";
            // 
            // fileToolStripMenuItem
            // 
            this.fileToolStripMenuItem.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.fileToolStripMenuItem.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0, 0, 20, 0);
            this.fileToolStripMenuItem.Name = "fileToolStripMenuItem";
            this.fileToolStripMenuItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(44, 24);
            this.fileToolStripMenuItem.Text = "File";
            // 
            // hmeToolStripMenuItem
            // 
            this.hmeToolStripMenuItem.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.hmeToolStripMenuItem.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0, 0, 20, 0);
            this.hmeToolStripMenuItem.Name = "hmeToolStripMenuItem";
            this.hmeToolStripMenuItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(53, 24);
            this.hmeToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Hme";
            // 
            // masterToolStripMenuItem
            // 
            this.masterToolStripMenuItem.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.masterToolStripMenuItem.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0, 0, 20, 0);
            this.masterToolStripMenuItem.Name = "masterToolStripMenuItem";
            this.masterToolStripMenuItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(66, 24);
            this.masterToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Master";
            // 
            // settingToolStripMenuItem
            // 
            this.settingToolStripMenuItem.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.settingToolStripMenuItem.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0, 0, 20, 0);
            this.settingToolStripMenuItem.Name = "settingToolStripMenuItem";
            this.settingToolStripMenuItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(68, 24);
            this.settingToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Setting";
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this.label1.AutoSize = true;
            this.label1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Montserrat", 15F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(128)))), ((int)(((byte)(0)))));
            this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(19, 9);
            this.label1.Name = "label1";
            this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(361, 30);
            this.label1.TabIndex = 3;
            this.label1.Text = "ThirdEye ERP HRM SYSTEM";
            // 
            // sidePanel
            // 
            this.sidePanel.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            this.sidePanel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(-1, 155);
            this.sidePanel.Name = "sidePanel";
            this.sidePanel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(10, 69);
            this.sidePanel.TabIndex = 2;
            // 
            // timer1
            // 
            this.timer1.Enabled = true;
            this.timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
            // 
            // timer2
            // 
            this.timer2.Interval = 15;
            this.timer2.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.timer2_Tick);
            // 
            // FrmMain
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(8F, 16F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1515, 902);
            this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
            this.MainMenuStrip = this.menuStrip1;
            this.Name = "FrmMain";
            this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            this.Text = "FrmMain";
            this.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized;
            this.flowLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout(false);
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).EndInit();
            this.panelCollap.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.panel1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.panel1.PerformLayout();
            this.panel3.ResumeLayout(false);
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox3)).EndInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox2)).EndInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox4)).EndInit();
            this.menuStrip1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.menuStrip1.PerformLayout();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel flowLayoutPanel1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnHome;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnMasterFiles;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnEmplyeeCenter;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnAttendence;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnLeave;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnPerformance;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnNoticeBoard;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Panel sidePanel;
        private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox4;
        private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox3;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label lblDate;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label lblTme;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.MenuStrip menuStrip1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem fileToolStripMenuItem;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem hmeToolStripMenuItem;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem masterToolStripMenuItem;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem employeeToolStripMenuItem;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem payrllToolStripMenuItem;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem attendenceToolStripMenuItem;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem leaveToolStripMenuItem;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem performanceToolStripMenuItem;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem noticeToolStripMenuItem;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem settingToolStripMenuItem;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnPayroll;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnSettings;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel3;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panelCollap;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnUserSetup;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnComanySetup;
    }
```

i just removed some buttons from design.cs cuz char limitation.
Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

You have a weird uncommented `</param>` at the line 6 of your `Designer.cs` file. You probably left it around after removing those button. Just remove it and it should work fine.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm sorry, I just mistake when I removing some lines cuz word limitation of the stack overflow. that's fine in my project

Comment: @NumeshVidurangaGamage: Are you sure that you saved the project before closing it? Please recheck everything because rationally such a thing may not be possible without reason. Check the following things:

1. Is it surely the same project that you were working on? Go to the repos folder and check the other solutions.
2. Did you mistakenly edit some other project or solution?
3. Did you surely open the same form that you were working on?